# operatiing quasi-coherator functor on a product of modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of $R$-modules. We know that  there are functors $^\widetilde{\  }: R{\rm -Mod}\to {\rm Qco(Spec}R)$ and $\Gamma({\rm Spec}R, -): {\rm Qco}({\rm Spec}R) \to R{\rm -Mod}$ which give us an equivalence of the category of $R$-modules and quasi-coherent $R$-modules.

1) What is the structure of $\widetilde{\prod_{i\in I}M_i}$?

2) Can we describe product objects in ${\rm Qco}({\rm Spec}R)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P = \prod_{i \in I}^{\mathsf{Mod}(\mathrm{Spec}(R))} \widetilde{M_i}$ and $Q = \prod_{i \in I}^{\mathsf{Qcoh}(\mathrm{Spec}(R))} \widetilde{M_i}$. The superscript indicates in which category the product is taken.

Then we have $Q = \widetilde{\prod_{i \in I} M_i}$, since $M \mapsto \widetilde{M}$ is an equivalence of categories $\mathsf{Mod}(R) \simeq \mathsf{Qcoh}(\mathrm{Spec}(R))$.

By the universal property of $P$, there is a canonical morphism $Q \to P$ in $\mathsf{Mod}(\mathrm{Spec}(R))$. On $D(f)$ it is induced by the canonical homomorphism of $R_f$-modules $(\prod_{i \in I} M_i)_f \to \prod_{i \in I} (M_i)_f$. It is easy to see that this homomorphism usually fails to be an isomorphism, even for $M_i=R$. In fact, $P$ is not quasi-coherent.

By the way, if $X$ is an arbitrary scheme, then $\mathsf{Qcoh}(X)$ still has arbitrary products, but they are not so easy to describe. One has to take the [quasi-coherator](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/077K) of the product taken in $\mathsf{Mod}(X)$.